# KeyError in console, but key exists and function works fine

Tags: python, json

I have looked at all the other keyerror questions on here, but I couldn't find one that addressed my situation. I am pulling location information from Google and reading the json info into a python list. Here is the part of the script that goes iterates over the results from Google.

```
results = []

# def get_data():
for term, (latitude, longitude, search_radius) in search_parameters.items():
    params = {
        'query': term,
        'location': (latitude, longitude),
        'radius': search_radius
    }
    geocode_result = gmaps.places(**params)
    for i in geocode_result['results']:

        results.append(i['name'])
        results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lat'])
        results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lng'])
        results.append(i['formatted_address'])
        results.append(i['opening_hours']['open_now'])
        results.append(i['price_level'])
        results.append(i['rating'])
        results.append(i['types'])

    if 'next_page_token' in geocode_result.keys():
        while 'next_page_token' in geocode_result.keys():
            time.sleep(2.5)
            params.update({'page_token': geocode_result['next_page_token']})
            geocode_result = gmaps.places(**params)
            for i in geocode_result['results']:
                results.append(i['name'])
                results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lat'])
                results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lng'])
                results.append(i['formatted_address'])
                results.append(i['opening_hours']['open_now'])
                results.append(i['price_level'])
                results.append(i['rating'])
                results.append(i['types'])
    else:
        break

    print(results)
```

Here is an example of the json style python code that it is pulling from.

```
[{
  'html_attributions': [],
  'next_page_token': 'CpQCBgEAAFzW9_qpkvmXV8sFiwXg6dEp2jsZXEqQOO4upW1U0FZPK0kiJvSmEbx4EuhAtDD4vtJcC4duqCj6oo0P68cRkGArenzZQWr61Wne0vA44R16SrfCDWLxQjqUu8zUcdLvdB7HfOHPMd7-KWK4cmX-6bLYIJldmnJBeqhnR5xmtB_TGlMyGlzh4vZ4kOB8dc1bnD6ijWxfFyz8wJ1ugA_5hZHLXtCY6NkE8TVYgTTV9710puKlKgiVSSkjwV3IsGgEhzixzGRrVHg2dB3Ehv2KHRuXnvIQJHr-CIkUoK79vI-45pyitdYlW1h9UQk_fzDsIeec3PNE5Qz6kN--NcDv-_jzFBr7QS2RGLkAcZX4aFdfEhCoP3MAVgjsl_tKdYaIX8y_GhSvCFZSxLfWVDAyF--7T6l32G0YFw',
  'results': [{
    'formatted_address': '2222 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States',
    'geometry': {
      'location': {
        'lat': 32.7935,
        'lng': -96.8021119
      },
      'viewport': {
        'northeast': {
          'lat': 32.7948813802915,
          'lng': -96.8009040197085
        },
        'southwest': {
          'lat': 32.7921834197085,
          'lng': -96.8036019802915
        }
      }
    },
    'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png',
    'id': '26ba45975d09c8889ea321078b6bf10ceff07359',
    'name': 'Smashburger',
    'opening_hours': {
      'open_now': True,
      'weekday_text': []
    },
    'photos': [{
      'height': 3024,
      'html_attributions': ['<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107709113475800121508/photos">Terry Wint Jr</a>'],
      'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAA9BPb8sP5KUp9bLAgSd9dPQzH15TkG3sw5T6qOa-WSV1hi-3DLIhVzWI5woD2GtSl3aktKXTXktLUfr9vpum-XywbqFMKunee-YhWwPtwOGJaO5lULU-g1px7Z6lPUFvqEhDrofF3_89I455YRKo2hZuFGhRilVDqXdt5x2jPieN3W07UvJwsvA',
      'width': 4032
    }],
    'place_id': 'ChIJ22Ci9y-ZToYRDw1hkXkjceY',
    'price_level': 1,
    'rating': 4.1,
    'reference': 'CmRSAAAAzQIvy0nuhTQpRoAFTlilcVY_BfqGFj7gNlpNeIecwOWGV1x0qFm80zkPYFYKtJ15ilHYSoQbDH2wsQ_vahw5ilhriHA0EBWavcyev4mYVgNWssL0neY5d7YwOLAgtSEvEhBN6e_DakrfQPVtqkagEtQ4GhRCdi5cZ6CKfk6AqXkuGJ9ZVpuR-A',
    'types': ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
  },
```

I am getting this traceback error in terminal when i run it, but when I print my results everything is returning with no issues.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 52, in <module>
    results.append(i['price_level'])
KeyError: 'price_level'
```

Comment: Are you sure all results have a `price_level`? I cannot reproduce the issue by copying and pasting your code and your example document

Comment: Yes, here is what I am getting back in terminal for each pass through.
`'Whataburger', 32.8594031, -96.768596, '6061 Greenville Ave, Dallas, TX 75206, United States', True, 1, 4, ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']`
The `price_level` being 1

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me: what is the code and the input that gives you the exception?

Comment: Forgive me because I am still trying to learn python, but I don't understand what you are asking. Whenever I try to run the for loop above, which is the majority of the script, I get the results that I want. I get a `results` list that has all of the items that I append to it. For some reason, I still get a `KeyError: 'price_level'` in terminal despite the code running completely and giving me back all the correct information. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you get an output and then an exception, I think that the code you're looking at is not the cause of the problem. Are you sure that line 52 in your `testing.py` is from the same code you posted here?

Comment: Alternatively, to debug the issue, you can try pdb: `python3 -m pdb testing.py`, then press `c` ("continue"). The execution will stop when the exception is thrown. Typing `!i` and `!geocode_result` will let you inspect the contents of your variables

Comment: I think the issue might have had to do with where I had the print function? Thanks a ton for telling me about the `python3 -m pdb testing.py`. It is showing that there is no `'price_level'` in `!i`, but it is in the `!geocode_result`. I updated my script to show more of the code.

Comment: It'd still be useful to know what this `i` is and where line 52 is

Comment: Do you mind messaging me @AndreaCorbellini ? I don't have enough points to message. I found out what I think is the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145482/created-a-dictionary-but-some-of-the-key-value-pairs-seem-to-be-missing-or-not-t
Link to the new ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a few people have pointed out, directly and indirectly, I should start a new ticket for the issue that I am facing. The issue is that the value that I was calling `'price_level'` is not a key in `'geocode_result'`. Some how I was still able to get the values from calling it, but the keyerror was triggered post-output. Now I have to figure out how to turn `'price_level`' into a key.

Thank you all for your help in figuring this out.

Turns out the issue was that not all of the responses being fed back contained all the key's that I was calling. That is why it would run for what seemed like the entire script, and then stop when the keyerror was raised towards the end. I'm going to add a try statement to the for loop section.

Comment: Link to the new ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145482/created-a-dictionary-but-some-of-the-key-value-pairs-seem-to-be-missing-or-not-t

Answer (score 0):

Actually "price_level" is outside of the list.

You'll have it with `geocode_result['price_level']`

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Can't believe I missed that. Can you tell me why I am still getting price_level and all the other items outside of the list?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It's another problem. Your issue as the title says, is your keyError.
This is solved, right ?
If you have another issue (more global maybe), please open another ticket.

Answer (score 0):

keys in json file have to be double quoted - in my honest opinion.

"In JSON, keys must be strings, written with double quotes"
from here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The one posted on the question is not JSON, it's the Python representation of the decoded JSON object. In Python, both double quotes and single quotes are fine

Comment: It's not just your opinion, it's part of the spec.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Not sure about that ("Here is an example of the json that it is pulling from.")

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake that is what I am receiving back in terminal, but I do believe that it is Python based. I should have clarified.

Comment: Looking at the error message, that does make a lot of sense (since you'd get some sort of decoding exception otherwise). Still, I think it would be a good idea to edit the question slightly.