# Created a dictionary but some of the key value pairs seem to be missing or not transfering

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am having an issue with feeding in json style python code converting to a dictionary. I am using a pulling location data from Google and getting all the data that I need. However, whenever I create a dictionary from the list of data, some of the key:value pairs are missing.

Here is the json style python code that I get back.

```
{
  'html_attributions': [],
  'next_page_token': 'CpQCBgEAAFzW9_qpkvmXV8sFiwXg6dEp2jsZXEqQOO4upW1U0FZPK0kiJvSmEbx4EuhAtDD4vtJcC4duqCj6oo0P68cRkGArenzZQWr61Wne0vA44R16SrfCDWLxQjqUu8zUcdLvdB7HfOHPMd7-KWK4cmX-6bLYIJldmnJBeqhnR5xmtB_TGlMyGlzh4vZ4kOB8dc1bnD6ijWxfFyz8wJ1ugA_5hZHLXtCY6NkE8TVYgTTV9710puKlKgiVSSkjwV3IsGgEhzixzGRrVHg2dB3Ehv2KHRuXnvIQJHr-CIkUoK79vI-45pyitdYlW1h9UQk_fzDsIeec3PNE5Qz6kN--NcDv-_jzFBr7QS2RGLkAcZX4aFdfEhCoP3MAVgjsl_tKdYaIX8y_GhSvCFZSxLfWVDAyF--7T6l32G0YFw',
  'results': [{
    'formatted_address': '2222 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States',
    'geometry': {
      'location': {
        'lat': 32.7935,
        'lng': -96.8021119
      },
      'viewport': {
        'northeast': {
          'lat': 32.7948813802915,
          'lng': -96.8009040197085
        },
        'southwest': {
          'lat': 32.7921834197085,
          'lng': -96.8036019802915
        }
      }
    },
    'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png',
    'id': '26ba45975d09c8889ea321078b6bf10ceff07359',
    'name': 'Smashburger',
    'opening_hours': {
      'open_now': True,
      'weekday_text': []
    },
    'photos': [{
      'height': 3024,
      'html_attributions': ['<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107709113475800121508/photos">Terry Wint Jr</a>'],
      'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAA9BPb8sP5KUp9bLAgSd9dPQzH15TkG3sw5T6qOa-WSV1hi-3DLIhVzWI5woD2GtSl3aktKXTXktLUfr9vpum-XywbqFMKunee-YhWwPtwOGJaO5lULU-g1px7Z6lPUFvqEhDrofF3_89I455YRKo2hZuFGhRilVDqXdt5x2jPieN3W07UvJwsvA',
      'width': 4032
    }],
    'place_id': 'ChIJ22Ci9y-ZToYRDw1hkXkjceY',
    'price_level': 1,
    'rating': 4.1,
    'reference': 'CmRSAAAAzQIvy0nuhTQpRoAFTlilcVY_BfqGFj7gNlpNeIecwOWGV1x0qFm80zkPYFYKtJ15ilHYSoQbDH2wsQ_vahw5ilhriHA0EBWavcyev4mYVgNWssL0neY5d7YwOLAgtSEvEhBN6e_DakrfQPVtqkagEtQ4GhRCdi5cZ6CKfk6AqXkuGJ9ZVpuR-A',
    'types': ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
  }
```

As was pointed out to me in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142785/keyerror-in-console-but-key-exists-and-function-works-fine/46145379#46145379) `'price_level'` is outside of the `'results'` list. However, whenever I call for '`geocode_result.keys()'`, I only get `'html_attributes', 'next_page_token', 'results', 'status'`.

Here is the code that I am running.

```
results = []

# def get_data():
for term, (latitude, longitude, search_radius) in search_parameters.items():
    params = {
        'query': term,
        'location': (latitude, longitude),
        'radius': search_radius
    }
    geocode_result = gmaps.places(**params)
    for i in geocode_result['results']:

        results.append(i['name'])
        results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lat'])
        results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lng'])
        results.append(i['formatted_address'])
        results.append(i['opening_hours']['open_now'])
        results.append(i['price_level'])
        results.append(i['rating'])
        results.append(i['types'])

    if 'next_page_token' in geocode_result.keys():
        while 'next_page_token' in geocode_result.keys():
            time.sleep(2.5)
            params.update({'page_token': geocode_result['next_page_token']})
            geocode_result = gmaps.places(**params)
            for i in geocode_result['results']:
                results.append(i['name'])
                results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lat'])
                results.append(i['geometry']['location']['lng'])
                results.append(i['formatted_address'])
                results.append(i['opening_hours']['open_now'])
                results.append(i['price_level'])
                results.append(i['rating'])
                results.append(i['types'])
    else:
        break

print(results)
```

I want to be able to pull the `'lat', 'lng', 'name', 'open_now', 'price_level', 'rating', 'types'`. I am able to call all except the last three because they are not being stored as key value pairs in `'geocode_result'`. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce this, plus `geocode_result` is a list so I don't know how you are iterating over it like it is a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied it over from a previous version, I will edit it now.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. I get back `['Smashburger',
 32.7935,
 -96.8021119,
 '2222 McKinney Ave, Dallas, TX 75201, United States',
 True,
 1,
 4.1,
 ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']]` is that not what you want?

Comment: Do you not get any keyerrors when you run it? I was able to run it, but I kept getting keyerrors afterwards, because `'price_level', 'rating', 'types'` are not keys of `'geocode_result'` or `'geocode_result['results']'`.

Comment: actually they are the keys, `['rating',
 'reference',
 'price_level',
 'place_id',
 'photos',
 'formatted_address',
 'id',
 'types',
 'icon',
 'name',
 'geometry',
 'opening_hours']`

Comment: That's so weird. 
I just ran `print(geocode_result.keys())` after line `geocode_result = gmaps.places(**params)` and this is what I get back.
`dict_keys(['html_attributions', 'next_page_token', 'results', 'status'])`. The results key does not include any of the three that I am looking for.

Comment: yes but you are searching in `geocode_result['results']` so you should be looking at `for i in geocode_result['results']:    print i.keys()`

Comment: Yup, you're completely right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"yes but you are searching in geocode_result['results'] so you should be looking at for i in geocode_result['results']: print i.keys()" - @aws_apprentice

But it turns out that the reason I was getting an error was that not all of the results had a 'price_level', so I am going to use a try statement to avoid that issue.